# What are the consequences of creating wxWidgets GUI components outside of OnInit?

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets

Normally the GUI components are created in the OnInit-method.
I noticed that it isn't actually necessary; you can create
wxFrame outside the entire wxApp-object and it'll still work.

Are there any serious consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can construct wxFrame outside of the wxApp object by using the global method wxEntryStart.

> ::wxEntryStart bool wxEntryStart(int& argc, wxChar **argv)
>
> This function can be used to perform the initialization of wxWidgets
>   if you can't use the default initialization code for any reason.
>
> If the function returns true, the initialization was successful and
>   the global wxApp object wxTheApp has been created. Moreover,
>   wxEntryCleanup must be called afterwards. If the function returns
>   false, a catastrophic initialization error occured and (at least the
>   GUI part of) the library can't be used at all.
>
> Notice that parameters argc and argv may be modified by this function.
>
> Include files

The only consequence of this seems to be that you should call wxEntryCleanup()

Comment: it's possible to call the wxApp-object explicitly only.
`
    wxEntryStart(argc, argv);
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, _("Title"));
    frame->Show();
    wxTheApp->OnInit();
    wxTheApp->OnRun();
    wxEntryCleanup();
`